# Which function can i use in vba similar to the one i used in sql

Tags: vba, excel-formula, vba7, vba6

i have tis code in sql and it works but which function can i use in vba to archive the same result.

RIGHT('00' + MONTH(lt.LveFromDate),2) --2021-03 --2021-03
--YEAR(lt.LveFromDate)

Comment: VBA has `Right`, `Month` and `Year` functions.

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
Sub test()
  Dim s As String
  Dim myDate As Date
  
  myDate = Date
  s = Format(myDate, "yyyy-mm")
    
End Sub
```